# Adobe reader XI font error with Chrome > print > save as pdf

Tags: macos, pdf, google-chrome, adobe

I have a strange error with Adobe Reader XI when opening documents saved from the web, using print save to pdf.

Preview does not have that problem with same document.

[image]

Looking at the fonts it shows the font, but there is nothing I can do about it in there.

[image]

Interestingly the problem is only with PDF's save from web after about March 1, 2013.

The older PDFs work fine!

I am using latest versions of

Adobe Reader

[image]

Chrome 26.0.1410.65

OS X 10.8.3

on MacBook Air mid 2012

Running the system Font check it shows the font to be OK.

[image]

*Just to add some bitching.
I used to smack my software department for writing Error message like this one.
I told them, since you already know what he problem is how about telling the customer/user what to about it.*

In summary:

1. Print any web page to PDF using the built-in Chrome option (not Print using system dialog)
2. open resulting PDF in Adobe Reader
3. get error message: "The font 'Times-Roman' contains bad / Flags"
4. opening the same file with Preview does not result in an error.
   printing the same page with the "system dialog" does not result in a bad PDF.

How do I fix the Chromes embedded font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Chrome bug.  It has been [marked fixed in version 27](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=170763), so the easiest thing to do would be to wait for the upgrade or to upgrade now.

To fix the existing PDFs, you can do the following:

1. Open the PDF in Preview
2. File->Save

This will rewrite the PDF so that it does not have the issue.